# Angular: How to use service made in a module by other Module?

Tags: angularjs, service, module, controller

Assuming I have a Module owns a SharedAppData Service:

```
angular.module(
    'ModuleD')
    .factory("SharedAppData", SharedAppData);
```

I want to access SharedAppData in ModuleA's controller. How to configure in ModuleA? Do I need to set a dependency in 'ModuleA' and how?

```
angular.module('ModuleA', [])
    .controller("PageController", PageController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would cause circular dependency.

You better create a new module for `SharedAppData` and refer it in both modules that require it

```
angular.module('ModuleD', [])
   .factory("SharedAppData", SharedAppData)...
```

Then

```
angular.module(
        'parent',
        ['ModuleA', 'Module B', 'ModuleC',`ModuleD` ])

angular.module('ModuleA', ['ModuleD'])
    .controller("PageController", PageController);
```

Comment: How to set it so that controller in ModuleA can use service from ModuleB? I tried a few and still can't make it works.

Comment: I am sorry I can't make my controller in ModuleA use ModuleD's service. I have to set something in controller dependency right?

Either .controller("PageController", ['SharedAppData', function(){}] OR .controller("PageController", ['ModuleD.SharedAppData', function(){}] are not working

Comment: The syntax to use the dependency is `.controller('PageController',function($scope,SharedAppData) {});`